# What does "hither unto" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> For ten years hast thou climbed **hither unto** my cave: thou wouldst
>   have wearied of thy light and of the journey, had it not been for me,
>   mine eagle, and my serpent.

Found this in Nietzche's Thus Spoke Zarathustra and I was wondering what it meant. Hither means "to or toward this place" and unto means "to", so what does "hither unto" mean? I am a little bit confused. Could it be possible that unto means something else here? Even if it meant "until" or "by" it would not make much sense.

Comment: You found it in an English translation of that German-language work, *Also Sprach Zarathustra*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those are two different (archaic) prepositions, not a collocation.

> For ten years you have climbed **here to** my cave.

**hither** (from-elsewhere-herewards)

Comment: Ah, ok, so hither means here and unto means to?

Comment: Ah, wait the definition means "to this place" or "toward this place", or simply "here". I read it as being "to" or "toward this place".

Comment: It's more of an adverb than a preposition. It modifies the verb, implying motion in a direction.

Comment: Hither is "to here", and is one of a threefold set of forms: "hither", "here", "hence".  "Hence" means "from here", and survives largely in mathematical and similar contexts.  There were similar groupings for "there" ("thither", "thence") and "where" ("whither", "whence").